# How to copy specific cells and paste to a new workbook

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

```
Sub Button3_Click()

'PURPOSE: To loop through all Excel files in a user specified folder and perform a set task on them
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog

'Optimize Macro Speed
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
  Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    With FldrPicker
      .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
      .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End With

'In Case of Cancel
NextCode:
  myPath = myPath
  If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
  myExtension = "*.xlsx"

'Target Path with Ending Extention
  myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)
    Set newWb = Workbooks.Add
    With newWb
        .SaveAs Filename:=myPath & Left(myFile, 5) & "_import.xlsx"
    End With
'Loop through each Excel file in folder
  i = 2
  Do While myFile <> ""

    'Set variable equal to opened workbook
      Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)
      Set newWb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & Left(myFile, 5) & "_import.xlsx")
    'Change First Worksheet's Background Fill Blue
      wb.Sheets("Textual elements").Range("J11").Copy _
      Destination:=newWb.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1)
      wb.Worksheets("Textual elements").Range("J31").Copy _
      Destination:=newWb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2)

    i = i + 1

    'Save and Close Workbook
      newWb.Close SaveChanges:=True
    'Get next file name
      myFile = Dir()
  Loop
'Message Box when tasks are completed
  MsgBox "Task Complete!"

ResetSettings:
  'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

So I took the code from below site tried to edit according to my needs, but I get error italicized row in debugging mode.

The intention is to open a new workbook named as selected the folder and copy the cells to specific cells.

http://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/the-code-vault/2014/4/23/loop-through-all-excel-files-in-a-given-folder

Comment: @Ralph is this ok this time?..if so could you please delete "How to copy specific cells from excel files in a given path and from it's child folders to a new workbook"

Comment: How many records are you copying at a time and how much time does it take?

Answer (score 0):

I am still using Excel2002 so it doesn't play nice with xlsx files all the time.  That said, you may not need the line

```
set newWb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & Left(myFile, 5) & "_import.xlsx")
```

as I believe the workbook should open when it is added (possibly different in new versions).

When it comes to copying the range from one workbook to another

```
wb.Worksheets("Textual elements").Range("J11").Copy Destination:=newWb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(i, 1))
```

I am not sure if you have the Do While myFile <> "" loops set properly.  You are ensuring myFile <> "" then doing something but not changing myFile's value and checking again that myFile <> ""

Also if you run this macro, it will overwrite the specified cells each time it is run so you will only have the most recent data - just incase that's not what you're trying to do.

**EDIT**
I still don't think you need to open the newwb when you have just opened it - might be best to step through the code using F8 & F9 to test that.

With regards the copying, I was right that you should use copy : destination, but hadn't noticed you were trying to range a cell.  It should be either Range() OR cell().  Try this:

```
  wb.Sheets("Textual elements").Range("J11").Copy _
    Destination:=newWb.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1)
  wb.Worksheets("Textual elements").Range("J31").Copy _
    Destination:=newWb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2)
```

The space underscore ' _' at the end of copy is just to take the codee to a new line for ease of reading (so it doesn't go off the end of the page)

At the end of your code you are closing wb and saving changes even though you have not made any changes.  I would change this to newwb and close wb without saving changes.

Comment: I followed your steps but still got the run-time error '1004'; Application-defined or object-defined error at the same place.

Comment: It's after midnight here, so I may not be around for long.  I would advise checking out the [mrexcel.com forum](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/) - alot of good examples and help to be had there.  That said, click on that line of code and press F9 - run your code and it will run to that point.  Press F8 to continue 1 line at a time.  When you get an error, paste that line of text here and we can try to fix it.

Comment: Thnx so much ... I've been digging every excel site over 12 hours :D . And I manage to came up with this :)

Comment: I have update the code as your comment and it started working ( Hurray :D) but the thing is I don't know how this do while loop working with myFile <>"" but there is a line as 
'Get next file name
      **myFile = Dir()**
  Loop
guess this changes it but since the code couldn't manage to run even 1 cycle there is a new problem popped up .. everything working fine but eventually it tries to open the excel file which code created it self so there should another control line added to the loop. So i tried but I really embarrassed to write :D  myFile <>"" or myFile=Left(myFile, 5) & "_import.xlsx"

Comment: Okay, I think you need to edit your original post - as I did, just put the edit details at the bottom and go through step by step what you are wanting to achieve.  Also state where your macro will be running from - is this going to be a master workbook that you use to create all these other documents?

Comment: Well actually I need to do here
master folder (No excel sheets in it but a shit load of folders)> Child (here are the excel files)> and there may be Child's child folder and if so skip the excel files on the parent and run the copy process in here. 
Copy Process 
in the excel sheets copy J11 and J31 paste them to a new workbook 's A2(some other content + the copy) and B2 which should be named after the excel file's first 5 letters. and save it to the master folder.

Comment: I just edited the code in here but I couldn't be sure if I set 
'Save and Close Workbook
      newWb.Close SaveChanges:=True
to false is workbook still has the copied content ?

Comment: So you have a master folder with nothing but folders in it.  These subfolders contain the excel files and possibly more folders?  If the subfolder has folders in it, you don't want the excel file to do anything, but you want to look in the other folders (1 or more? will these contain folders also?)  - so the master folder will end up with all the _import workbooks in it?  Where is the workbook that contains your macro going to be saved?  Is this in the master folder too or elsewhere?

Comment: Master Folder (Containts only folders)>Excel file and maybe 1 folder(no more than 1)>Just excel file no more folder in this level. Can I reach you to chat I don't know is it OK in this platform to share e-mail or something else to chat and also if you want it.
BTW I am totally aware that this code won't do what I needed but I don't have such knowledge to build what I need that's why I'm trying to use this one.

Comment: I would advise making a post on the MrExcel forum mentioned in the 2nd comment above.  The layout is more conducive for commenting many times on a problem.  I will pop over there to assist, but you will also get the benefit of many other Excel programmers.  I am doing some other work right now so chat is not really an option.  I would not share your email on an open forum though - only through private messaging.  Not sure this site has that though.  Explain what you are trying to achieve and state step by step how you would do this manually.

Comment: Thanks for help @glib ... will do that

Answer (score 0):

The Range-object does not have a Paste method, so it cannot identify the Paste statement. Hence the error. You can use PasteSpecial though.

Try this:

replace:

```
  wb.Worksheets("Textual elements").Range("J11").Copy
  newWb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(i, 1)).Paste
  wb.Worksheets("Textual elements").Range("J11").Copy
  newWb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(i, 2)).Paste
```

with:

```
 wb.Worksheets("Textual elements").Range("J11").Copy
 newWb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(i, 1),Cells(i,2)).PasteSpecial
```

or without PasteSpecial:

```
 wb.Worksheets("Textual elements").Range("J11").Copy newWb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(i, 1),Cells(i,2))
```

or even, if you must use Paste ;-):

```
 wb.Worksheets("Textual elements").Range("J11").Copy
 newWb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(i, 1),Cells(i,2)).select
 ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Comment: I have tried all your offers and removed the sloppy codes as @glib told me and edited the cells should be copied but still got an error on the bold one.
About your replacement codes when the code gave the error the sheet contains data is left open and the J11 cell copied but can't manage to paste and the new workbook just left open A1 cell selected. 
Codes ending with "Activesheet.paste" and the "without pastespecial" one are gave the same error but they didn't copy the J11
wb.Worksheets("Textual elements").Range("J11").Copy
       **newWb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(i, 1)).PasteSpecial**

Comment: Sorry to hear that. It worked on my end. The last thing i can think off: Are you sure you are not copying to a protected range?

Comment: I'm not sure if Dinçer has the correct range here.  Using Range you can have "J11" or "J11:J11".  Using range of cells Range(cells()) you can have Range(cells(i,1),cells(i,1)) so there is a start and end, but not just Range(cells(i,1)) - this would not work.  Also, it would only work if the cells were on the workbook that the code was in, otherwise you would need to specify for the range and each cell:  newWb.sheets("Sheet1").Range(newWb.sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1),newWb.sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1))